# Angular5 - google contacts api integration - The values are changed in component but not reflecting in HTML

Tags: angular, google-contacts-api

I have integrated the google contacts in the website successfully. But the problem is, the contacts is not listed in the html even after assigns those to the component variables. 
ie.

On clicking the google button, it opens up a new window and closes after authentication. We are fetching the contacts using the token and getting properly, but the html part is not reflecting until we do a click or keypress .

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, TemplateRef, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AbstractControl, FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { UserService } from '../../services/user-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slide-panel',
  templateUrl: './slide-panel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slide-panel.component.css']
})
export class SlidePanelComponent implements OnInit {
googleContacts = [];
constructor(private modalService: BsModalService, 
        private router: Router,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private userService: UserService) {
  }
onGettingGoogleContacts(gcontacts: any) {
this.googleContacts = gcontacts;
}
}
```

**component.html**

```
 <google-signin (gotGoogleContacts)="onGettingGoogleContacts($event)"></google-signin>
<div class="select-from-list" *ngIf="googleContacts.length > 0">
    <ul>
        <li class="clearfix" *ngFor="let contact of googleContacts">
            <div class="checkboxnew">
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"><i></i>
                <h5>{{contact.firstName}} {{contact.lastName}}<span>{{contact.email}}</span></h5>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="text-right">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-link" (click)="formType = 'inviteColleague'">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Import</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**child-component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, EventEmitter, Input, Output  } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../../services/user-service';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

declare const gapi: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'google-signin',
  templateUrl: './google-signin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./google-signin.component.css']
})
export class GoogleSigninComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @Output() gotGoogleContacts = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

    private clientId:string = environment.google_contacts_client_id;
    private scope = [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
    ].join(' ');

  constructor(private element: ElementRef, private userService: UserService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public auth2: any;

  /**
   * Inialize google signin config
   */
  public googleInit() {
    gapi.load('auth2', () => {
      this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: this.clientId,
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
        scope: this.scope
      });
      this.attachSignin(this.element.nativeElement.firstChild);
    });
  }

  /**
   * Attach signin process and get the google contacts
   * @param Object  element
   */
  public attachSignin(element) {
    this.auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
       (googleUser) => {
        this.userService.getGoogleContactsData(googleUser.getAuthResponse().access_token)
        .subscribe((data) => {
            if (data) {
                this.passGoogleContacts(data.feed.entry || []);
            }
        });
      }, (error, data) => {
            this.passGoogleContacts([]);
      });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.googleInit();
  }

  /**
   * Pass google contacts to the parent
   */
  passGoogleContacts(contacts: any) {
    this.gotGoogleContacts.emit(contacts);
  }

}
```

**user-service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from './http.service';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Http, ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    constructor(
        public _http: HttpService) { }


    getGoogleContactsData(token) {
        return this._http.request(endUserApi.googleContactsApiUrl + `&access_token=${token}`)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

I this code the function onGettingGoogleContacts() is called from the child component when the contacts is getting.

I used this [mechanism](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-observable-interval-gu7c3r) to get the contacts.

Any solution to automatically reflect those changes in the html?

Comment: could you provide some code ?

Comment: `(gotGoogleContacts)="onGettingGoogleContacts($event)"` in this code `$event` is a boolean (`@Output() gotGoogleContacts = new EventEmitter<boolean>();`)

Comment: I have replaced with Array that code but no effect. But before that also the google contacts is getting and reflecting in html when we click anywhere in the window.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're using the API to updating some object without changing the object itself.
Can you show use your api integration ? do you use rxjs or smoething like that ?
Or a simple callback / promise ?

If so, maybe try something like that

```
onGettingGoogleContacts(gcontacts: any) {
   this.googleContacts = ...gcontacts;
}
```

this will create a clone of your data, and thus provoque the reflecting

Comment: Can you go through this to get an idea of the implementation of google contacts api I have used: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-observable-interval-gu7c3r

Comment: it seems to be callback based, I don't see where rxjs is used here. So my money is still on a "object property update" related bug ^^

Comment: btw, you could also update your data to be some sort or RXJS Subject, then use the AsyncPipe to display it on your html. This will that care of that type of problem for you

Comment: I have already used the rxjs for getting the google contacts. I will edit the question by including that code as well

Comment: can you try my first answer and just add the "..." to clone ?

Comment: simpler option, in your "userService" transform your method to use ReplaySubject ( https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/replaysubject.md ) then both your component could subscribe to the same subject and reflect at the same time

Comment: But the function named this._http.request is already an observable function. Whether this will do that job rt?

Comment: I am showing this in a modal(ngx-bootstrap/modal). Is that a problem?

Comment: The modal is not the problem. All observable doesn't act the same way. You need to learn about hot and cold observable ( https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/getting-started-with-rxjs-part-3-hot-and-cold-observables-4713757c9a88 ) http request will be triggered each time someone subscribe, this is not the case with an replaysubject. so if you want multiple subscription, without having multiple api call, you need RS :)